# Disable apache2 log

Tags: php, apache, apache2, debian

I only have 32GB on my server, and the logs is eating up that space quickly. So I want to disable the logs.

I think I found where to do it, but since I'm a complete noob when it comes to server, I don't want to start changing things without being sure that they won't crash the server.

In etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I found this:

```
    #
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

and in etc/apache2/conf.d/other-vhost-access-log, I found this:

```
# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined
```

What do I need to do to disable the logs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add log rotate to system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you truly want to disable the logs, you must comment out any `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives in your Apache configuration files. On Debian, these will be located in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (the base configuration) and then `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*` (specific virtual host configurations).

You can comment them out by adding a '#' character in front of them.

Once the changes are made, run `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` for the changes to take effect.

IMO, a better solution -- since logs are often very handy -- is to install log rotate as Sergey suggested above. In Debian, run this:

```
 sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

logrotate will, in its default configuration, split logs daily and compress the old ones, saving a ton of disk space while preserving the logs themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... Can I just run the script above and it will work, or do I need to configure some files?

Comment: For logrotate, simply run the command above. The Debian package will automatically configure logrotate with the default settings, which will cycle daily and compress old logs. You can play with the configuration in `/etc/logrotate.conf` if necessary, and I believe the Debian package places application-specific logrotate configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d`.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here is wrong. Commenting out that line does not disable the errorlog, it just reverts it to the apache2 default. From the apache2 [ErrorLog documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog):

> Default:  ErrorLog logs/error_log (Unix) ErrorLog logs/error.log (Windows and OS/2)

In other words, this will be somewhere in the apache installation root 'logs' directory.

To disable I think you'll need to recompile without logging support (not sure if even possible), or pipe ErrorLog to /dev/null:

> ErrorLog "|/dev/null"

Comment: This is the correct answer, you will CERTAINLY fill your disk space -- as we have just done, by commenting out and restarting apache.

Comment: Just `ErrorLog /dev/null` is good. The pipe character "|" means that the following path is a command to handle the log. There is no need to use pipe here since `/dev/null` is not a command.